# Firebase Authentication (email and password) How to check if user still exists?

Tags: android, firebase, firebase-authentication

I'm using Firebase Authentication in my app (email and password auth).
In the `onStart()` method of my Login activity I retrieve the current user using:

```
FirebaseUser currentUser = mAuth.getCurrentUser();
```

The problem comes when the user is deleted from the database, the `mAuth.getCurrentUser()` method still retrieves the user and allows authentication.
How can I check if the user still exists?
Thx!

Comment: Please add your database structure and the code that you are using.

Answer (score 0):

Try using something like this:

```
DatabaseReference ref = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference();
ref.child("users").child("email").addListenerForSingleValueEvent(new 
ValueEventListener() {
  @Override
  public void onDataChange(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {
      if(dataSnapshot.exists()){
          // used "email" already exists and is not deleted
      } else {
          // User does not exist. Add here your logic if the user doesn't exist
      }                               
  }

  @Override
  public void onCancelled(DatabaseError databaseError) {

  }
});
```

Or check some of the following SO questions and answers:

[Firebase authentication for checking if the user exists in the database or not](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48500719/firebase-authentication-for-checking-if-the-user-exists-in-the-database-or-not)

[Firebase Auth - with Email and Password - Check user already registered](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40012816/firebase-auth-with-email-and-password-check-user-already-registered)

Answer (score 0):

You can use getInstance. This worked for me fine. You don't get an instance with it.

```
private boolean isSignedIn() {
        return FirebaseAuth.getInstance().getCurrentUser() != null;
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

Delete the userdata and make the currentuser `null`:
Follow the below code.

```
     final FirebaseUser user = FirebaseAuth.getInstance().getCurrentUser();


           user.delete()
            .addOnCompleteListener(new OnCompleteListener<Void>() {
                @Override
                public void onComplete(@NonNull Task<Void> task) {
                    if (task.isSuccessful()) {
                        Log.d(TAG, "User account deleted.");
                        //Remove the information f the user from database.
                    }
                }
            });
```

Answer (score 0):

The code below works great on android to confirm if the Firebase Auth user still exists (has not been deleted or disabled) and has valid credentials.

Deleting the Auth user from the firebase console does not revoke auth tokens on devices the user is currently logged in as the token is cached locally. Using reload() forces a check with the firebase auth server.

```
currentUser.reload().addOnCompleteListener(new OnCompleteListener<Void>() {
                @Override
                public void onComplete(@NonNull Task<Void> task) {
                    if(task.isSuccessful()){
                        //User still exists and credentials are valid

                    }else {
                        //User has been disabled, deleted or login credentials are no longer valid, 
                        //so send them to Login screen
                    }
                }
            });
```